# use of update or saveorupdate method in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

If the object is managed anyways its state is going to tracked and any changes made to this object will be going to updated in the database automatically as a part of dirty checking, so why the `update` or `saveOrUpdate` method are needed?

## Update

And why do update and saveOrUpdate method throw exception if we try to save detached object and that object is associated with session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the update or saveOrUpdate method are needed?

The second part of your question answers the first part: the methods are used to update a *detached* object, whose state is *not* tracked by Hibernate.

> why do update and saveOrUpdate method throw exception if we try to save detached object and that object is associated with session?

Because Hibernate provides a guarantee (that is crucial to its own correct behavior): inside a session, there can only be one instance of a given entity. Since update() and saveOrUpdate() take a detached entity and make it attached, if there is already an attached version of that entity in the session and Hibernate didn't throw an exception, you would end up with two attached instances of the same entity in the same session. And that would thus break the Hibernate guarantee. What would happen if user1 and user2 were two attached instances of the User with ID 42:

```
user1.setName("Foo");
user2.setName("Bar");
```

Now you commit the transaction: what should be the name of the user?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, One more doubt I have it, why merge method creates a copy while persisting an entity?

Comment: To allow saving the state of a detached entity without throwing an exception as update() does: by copying the state of the detached entity to the attached one, and thus preserve the uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: But in case of transient instance the object is not present into the Persistent context then why a copy is needed?

Comment: One more is what is the use of merge method with transient object?

Comment: In the case of transient instances, it's not present, but in the case of persistent instances, they can be present. The main use-case is to update a persistent entity. To save a new one, persist() is more appropriate.